# jquery - how to continue the execution of one function once another function has returned a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, return, promise

I currently have a function called showAuthorInfo which performs an animation, and then executes some other code logic once the animation is finished:

```
self.showAuthorInfo = function(){
  var authorID = $authorLink.attr('data-author-id'); //PL-INT - determine what info needs be captured here
  var isActive = $modalInfoWindow.hasClass('active');
  self.$modalInfoWindow.animate({ 'bottom': '0px' },200,function(){

    self.$modalInfoWindow.addClass('active');
    self.loadAuthorInfo(authorID);

  })

}
```

however, because I will want to show and hide this modal window via various function calls, executing different callbacks each time the animation is completed, I'd like to wrap the animation into a function. The question is, can I use the above function to call a custom function where the animation happens, and have that animation function return a value to this function, whereon it can then proceed?

I would break the function up into multiple functions, but I feel like that could get complicated, especially because I would have to pass on certain function-specific parameters that wouldn't apply to all cases (for example, in the code above, if I were going to call an animation function, and then a loadAuthorInfo function, the animation function would have to accept authorID so it could pass it on to loadAuthorInfo, even though the animation function only needs authorID if it is called by showAuthorInfo).

Any recommendations here?

Example of what I'd rather NOT do:

```
self.showAuthorInfo = function(){
  var authorID = $authorLink.attr('data-author-id'); //PL-INT - determine what info needs be captured here
  var callback = self.displayAuthorContent();
  self.animateInfoWindow(authorID,callback);
}

self.animateInfoWindow = function(authorID,callback){
  self.$modalInfoWindow.animate({ 'bottom': '0px' },200,function(){

    //create conditional where if there's an authorID, pass it to the callback function, otherwise just call the callback function without parameters

  })
}
```

Comment: `showAuthorInfo` is a function call or a function declaration? It seems that you are calling it and declaring it. Can you provide some more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mheavers, you've tagged your question with `promise`, which means you are thinking along the right lines.

It's maybe little appreciated that jQuery allows *ad hoc* promises to be formed from jQuery collections, with `$(selector).promise(type, target)`, typically at the end of a longer method chain. `type` defaults to "fx" (the standard animation queue), and target is optional (and not relevant here).

Thus, `self.animateInfoWindow` can be blissfully unaware of anything that will happen after the animation it kicks off has completed. All it needs to do is return a promise of the type described above, thus allowing chaining where `self.animateInfoWindow` is called.

```
self.animateInfoWindow = function() {
    return self.$modalInfoWindow.animate({'bottom':'0px'}, 200).promise();
};
```

And `self.showAuthorInfo` can perform the post-animation action without passing any params to `self.animateInfoWindow`.

```
self.showAuthorInfo = function() {
    var authorID = $authorLink.data('authorId') || null; //PL-INT - determine what info needs be captured here
    self.animateInfoWindow().done(function() {
        self.$modalInfoWindow.addClass('active');
        self.loadAuthorInfo(authorID);
  });
};
```

Note, `|| null` in the first line to ensure that `authorID` is not `undefined`. (Slightly more complicated if an authorId of 0 (zero) is valid).

The only other thing is to ensure that `self.loadAuthorInfo` is tollerant of being passed `null`.

Comment: Nice! This is exactly what I was looking to do, just wasn't sure how to structure it.

Comment: mh, one more thought; with this structure you could move the line `var authorID = ...` inside the `.done()` handler, thus avoiding the need for `self.showAuthorInfo` to form a closure, though doing so would mean `authorID` is not locked in before the animation starts. With an amination duration of 200ms it's probably not a big deal either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the callback to animate and avoid unnecessary function wrapping:

```
    self.showAuthorInfo = function(){
      var authorID = $authorLink.attr('data-author-id'); //PL-INT - determine what info needs be captured here
      var callback = self.displayAuthorContent();
      self.animateInfoWindow(authorID,function(){
        //do something here
      });
    }

    self.someOtherFunction = function(){
      var authorID2 = $authorLink2.attr('data-author-id2'); //PL-INT - determine what info needs be captured here
      var callback2 = self.displayAuthorContent2();
      self.animateInfoWindow(authorID2,function(){
        //do something different
      });
    }


    self.animateInfoWindow = function(authorID,callback){
      self.$modalInfoWindow.animate({ 'bottom': '0px' },200,callback)
    }
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95kwD/

I don't really know what you want to accomplish with:

```
var callback = self.displayAuthorContent();
```

You are calling the callback before calling the function which is the whole purpose of a callback function. Maybe it's just the name of the function `var`iable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep animateWindow as generic as possible, then just have a callback and no params. The callback can be more context-aware to allow flexibility.

```
self.showAuthorInfo = function(){
   var authorID = $authorLink.attr('data-author-id');
   var customCallback = function(){
       self.loadAuthorInfo(authorID);
   };
   self.animateInfoWindow(customCallback);
}
self.animateInfoWindow = function(callback){
   self.$modalInfoWindow.animate({ 'bottom': '0px' },200,callback);
}
```